# Does every TCP packet for a HTTP request contain a HTTP Header?

Tags: c, http, tcp

I am writing a packet sniffer and have to detect when packets come from a certain website. I was wondering if the packet always contains a header, or if it is only a select few.

Thanks

Comment: TCP isn't in the same layer as HTTP.

Comment: What does this happen to have with **C**?

Comment: I'd say, learn about OSI layers first before you start writing a packet sniffer. Or get a decent one (e.g. Wireshark) and learn from there.

Comment: You do not need TCP for HTTP!

Comment: Since you tagged this in C I took the liberty to find an appropriate duplicate that goes further.

Comment: @EdHeal just out of curiosity, have you ever encountered HTTP over something else than TCP in the wild?

Answer (score 2):

No.

TCP works on a different level in the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

Answer (score 1):

No. There are packets for the TCP handshake, and packets *could* contain only pieces of the request body.